# puppet enterprise ssl cert error

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm trying to install puppet enterprise on EC2.

The **puppet server** seems to work fine.

/etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1 puppet
```

puppet cert list --all : doesn't show anything

**On the puppet agent** :

/etc/hosts :

```
10.113.148.136     ip-10-113-148-136.ec2.internal     ip-10-113-148-136      puppet
```

when I run "puppet agent --test"

Error: Could not request certificate: The certificate retrieved from the master does not match the agent's private key. To fix this, remove the certificate from both the master and the agent and then start a puppet run, which will automatically regenerate a certificate.

On the master:

```
puppet cert clean bla1.example.com
```

On the agent:

```
rm -f /home/ubuntu/.puppet/ssl/certs/bla1.example.com.pem
puppet agent -t
```

When I run this command on the master. I get the error:

```
Error: Could not find a serial number for bla1.example.com
```

And when I run "puppet agent -t" I get the same error message

Also note that in the web-ui: bla1.example.com shows in the "unresponsive" list

When I run "puppet agent --server puppet --waitforcert 30 --test" 
I get the same error message and afterwards this message:

```
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/home/ubuntu/.puppet/var/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources     using 'eval_generate': SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey:: key values mismatch
Error: /File[/home/ubuntu/.puppet/var/lib]: Could not evaluate: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey::             key values mismatch Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/plugins:     SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey:: key values mismatch
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey:: key     values mismatch
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey:: key values mismatch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the puppet.conf: `server=FQDN` does the FQDN in the agents puppet.conf match the private key FQDN in the puppet master in `/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/`? I think I ran into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
# puppet cert sign <node>; puppet cert clean <node>
```

Comment: when I try "puppet cert sign bla1.example.com" i get: Error: Could not find certificate request for bla1.example.com. And when I try the second one I get Could not find a serial number for bla1.example.com.

Comment: Could you try connecting from agent first and then running cert sign?

Comment: I run "puppet agent --server puppet --waitforcert 30 --test" and get the same error message

Comment: Seems like this might be the same issue as http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/16657

Comment: actually when I run "puppet agent --server puppet --waitforcert 30 --test" and get the same error message plus some more info- see above

Comment: But you're still unable to run cert sign successfully on master, right?

What if you add * to /etc/puppet/autosign.conf?

Comment: The "/etc/puppet" folder does not exist in my version. When I do "puppet config print" it shows this item : "autosign = /home/ubuntu/.puppet/autosign.conf" , so I added this new file with only "*" in it. Afterwards I retried "puppet agent --test" but got the same error

Answer (score 0):

> Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey: key values mismatch

If you see those errors in your syslog from puppet agent interval runs (or when forced using `pkill -SIGUSR1 puppet`) after changing the certificates, try stop/starting the puppet agent. It may look like the agent is using the right `Certificate fingerprint: ...` value in the logs, but that error likely means the private key resident in memory doesn't match the new public cert.